# why inputs preserve value in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am working on angularjs. i have strange issue. i have 5 inputs i am updating these inputs using angularjs. problem is this when i am making manual changes in any input then angularjs is not updating these manual updated inputs. i am using inputs followings ways.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="emp.name" value="{{employee.name}}"/>
```

and

```
<input type="text" id="emp.name" name="name" ng-model="employee.name"/>
```

but nothing works. anyone knows why after manuall modification angularjs not updating value of input

Please see screenshot:

[image]

The following code is where I am attempting to empty the data.

```
$scope.$apply(function($scope){
    $scope.showDetail = true;
    $scope.employee = {};
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by manual changes? You shouldn't be manually changing the input, instead you should be changing the model `employee.name` and then, if needed, causing a digest.

Comment: Can you show your controller? Your first approach will not work since you did not specify ng-model.

Comment: you do know that inp.value!=inp.getAttribute("value") right?

Comment: yes you right document.getElementById('emp.name').getAttribute('value') showing value `null` and document.getElementById('emp.name').value is what i have changed

Comment: Why are you changing the value of the input instead of changing the model?

Comment: @KevinB user will click on input and type any value what he wants when he click on clear button that will make empty all models so other inputs are empty but modified input remain

Comment: Right, which if using the second approach will result in the model updating. What does that have to do with `document.getElementById`? When working with angular you shouldn't need to find an element by id.

Comment: Then all you should need to do is set `employee.name` to `""`, you shouldn't need to select the input element and modify it. If using 2nd approach in your question, changing `employee.name` to `""` will empty the input value.

Comment: i have added screenshot of my screen this can make better understand

Comment: Code would likely be more useful.

Comment: i have added code for make empty inputs @KevinB

Comment: Can you expand that code to include what causes that code to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that `$scope.employee` exists before you can use `employee.name` as a model in your input.

So somewhere in your link or controller function you should set

```
$scope.employee = { name: 'initialName' } // Or just '' for empty name
```

Then, also be careful with `$scope.$apply`, you need to do that only if your code is running asynchronously (or in the developper console of your browser for instance).

Finally, try not to replace the whole employee reference, but instead only clear its name with your function:

```
$scope.showDetail = true;
$scope.employee.name = ''; // If $scope.employee doesn't exists here, read my answer again
```

Here is a jsfiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10018/

Comment: its also not working `$scope.showDetail = true; $scope.employee.name = '';`

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle to show the point. We'd need more about your code to know what's wrong because it is supposed to work as you can see.